# How to check two parameter($other and $user) of function in laravel repository?

Tags: php, json, mongodb, laravel

How to check two parameter($other and $user) of function in laravel repository

I have this query:

```
 public function GetFriend($other,$user)
 {
  $list = $this->makeModel()
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('otheruser',$other)
                  ->orWhere('user_id',$user);
        })
        ->get();
        return $list;
 }
```

i have user table(MongoDB):

```
{ 
   _id : 59db41e78ed7bc5c0d000029,
   is_active : true
},
{ 
   _id : 59db41e78ed7bc5c0d000031,
   is_active : true
}
```

I have friend table(MongoDB):

```
{
    _id : 1234567890,
    otheruser : 59db41e78ed7bc5c0d000031,
    user_id : 59db41e78ed7bc5c0d000029,
    is_friend : true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the variables to the closure

```
 public function GetFriend($other, $user)
 {
      $list = $this->makeModel()
                   ->where(function ($query) use ($other, $user) {
                       $query->where('otheruser', $other)
                             ->orWhere('user_id', $user);
                   })->get();
      return $list;
 }
```

Comment: let me check :)

Thanks for replay

Comment: Record Empty :(

Comment: No record Found.
when i was put static value insted of two variable then got record perfect.

but when i put variables ($user, $other) then no record found.

Comment: do a `dd($other)` and `dd($user)` in your method to cross check whether you are getting the correct values

Comment: it's work, let me tell you one think, following condition will work or not public function GetFriend($other, $user)
 {
      $list = $this->makeModel()
                   ->where(function ($query) use ($other, $user) {
                       $query->where('otheruser', $other)
                             ->orWhere('user_id', $user);
                   })
       ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($other, $user) {
                       $query->where('otheruser', $user)
                             ->orWhere('user_id', $other);
                   })
       ->get(); 
 }

Comment: it's work or not???

->where(function ($query) use ($other, $user) {
                       $query->where('otheruser', $other)
                             ->orWhere('user_id', $user);
                   })
       ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($other, $user) {
                       $query->where('otheruser', $user)
                             ->orWhere('user_id', $other);
                   })

Comment: Instead of asking whether the code would work or not, why don't you execute the code and check that out for yourself, and btw adding another orWhere with the same conditionals doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pass the variables to the closure via use method.

```
public function GetFriend($other,$user)
 {
  $list = $this->makeModel()
        ->where(function ($query) use ($other, $user) {
            $query->where('otheruser',$other)
                  ->orWhere('user_id',$user);
        })
        ->get();
        return $list;
 }
```

Comment: No record Found. when i was put static value insted of two variable then got record perfect. but when i put variables ($user, $other) then no record found